# How are you handling rollback of static frontend deployed to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend

In the event that you somehow need to rollback to the previous working version.

Codedeploy supports blue green deploy for ECS. That works great, but how do you manage the same sort of thing in S3?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Object Versioning https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html. You will need to have enabled versioning on the bucket already though. If you're going through CloudFront you can do this and create an invalidation.

Comment: S3 object versioning cannot do it. File `a.txt` may have 3 versions while `b.txt` may have 12 versions - because you have deployed your site 12 times, but `a.txt` was only changed 2 times after the 1st deploy. Therefore if you have dozens/hundreds/thousands of files and many of them are in different versions, simply using the S3 object versioning won't allow you to rollback to a consistent "previous version" of your site. You need to know which files/versions belong to which deployment. That's not the entire solution.

Comment: @jweyrich the question mentions AWS CodeDeploy. With CodeDeploy you can deploy all files from your build together each time using application revisions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/application-revisions-register.html. Manually uploading files individually and not keeping them in sync is an anti-pattern which was not mentioned in the original question.